# Actkbd as service with systemd

Tags: systemd

A while ago I asked for how to stop a music player while the screen is locked. The answer was to use actkbd which works like a charm. Now I wanted to add actkbd as a service to systemd in order to start it automatically when booting. So as you can see the service is started correctly and it shows up in htop as well. Some output below:

```
[root@hostname init.d]# systemctl start actkbd.service
[root@hostname init.d]# systemctl status actkbd.service
actkbd.service - Actkbd: Daemon for X-independent shortcuts
      Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/actkbd.service)
      Active: active (running) since Tue, 10 Apr 2012 17:50:36 +0200; 2s ago
     Process: 23526 ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/actkbd -d /dev/input/event3 -D (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Main PID: 23527 (actkbd)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/actkbd.service
              └ 23527 /usr/local/sbin/actkbd -d /dev/input/event3 -D
[root@hostname init.d]# systemctl stop actkbd.service
[root@hostname init.d]# ps -C actkbd
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
```

I have the following `actkbd.service` file in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/`

```
[Unit]
Description=Actkbd: Daemon for X-independent shortcuts

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/actkbd -d /dev/input/event3 -D
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID
Restart=always
User=root
```

So the problem is that after starting the service with systemctl nothing happens if I press my usual shortcut for pausing Rhythmbox. If I instead just execute the command `/usr/local/sbin/actkbd -d /dev/input/event3 -D` via the a root terminal everything works fine. Why that?

Sorry if it's something obvious, I'm new to the systemd business but I couldn't find anything that helped me.

Cheers.

EDIT:
This is still not working. If somebody has some time I'd appreciate it if one could try and reproduce it. If that is possible then I will file a bug report.

Comment: I have yet to try `actkbd` with `systemd`, due to lack of time, but I suspect that your issue has something to do with `actkbd` being started before the input system is fully initialized - `actkbd` works fine when started as an LSB service on my development laptop. You should make sure that it is started after the `evdev` module is launched, and that your keyboard always has the same `eventX` device node.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Theodoros. The tests that I showed above were executed while everything was booted. So in theory all modules should be loaded. The device node should be fine too as executing the command manually works fine all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would like the user to be able to access the device and run the service unit then you'll need to make a `udev` rule and set the proper `MODES` to allow the user permission to access the device. Simply starting the unit file as `User=root` is incorrect since you are not running the session as root but as your user. When you run it from a root terminal you're activating a root terminal from inside your users session. To get more information on this look up information on `systemd --user`.

#### Putting together a udev rule

Use the following command to give you the information that you will need in order to populate the `udev` rule:

`udevadm info --path=$(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/input/event3)`

From the output of the above command create your udev rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/<device>.conf`. Open it in your favorite text editor and fill in the variables

```
 SUBSYSTEM=="device",
 SYSFS{idVendor}=="ID Vendor Here" ,
 SYSFS{idProduct}=="ID Model Here",
 MODE="666"
```

For more information on making and naming `udev` rules have a look at `man udev` or your Linux distribution's Wiki. After setting the rules, reboot. And then start the unit once logged into X.

Also, here is a **much** more sane system unit file then the one that you've provided.

```
[Unit]
Description=Actkbd: Daemon for X-independent shortcuts

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/actkbd -Dd /dev/input/event3
RemainAfterExit=yes
Type=forking
Restart=always
```